# Why is my JQuery DIV transparent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My Jquery ajax page loads and shows up in the DIV that lays itself over the other page elements but the DIV is transparent or it is in fact behind the other components and just looking like it is transparent and neds to render on top. How do I achieve a normal DIV over the other pages with a white background? Why is it difficult making an element not transparent? How can this be deafult behavior for a page element?

[image]

Javascript

```
function popup() {
    alert('opening popup');
    var popup = $('.newpopup');

  $.ajax({url:'/PandoraArendeWeb/popup.jsp',
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
            success: function(data) {   
                popup.html(data); 
                popup.show('fast');
            }
       }
   ); 

   /*
    popup.html("test"); 
    popup.show('fast');
    */
    var screen_width = $(document).width();
var screen_height = $(document).height();
var box_width = popup.width();
var box_height = popup.height();

var top = (screen_height - box_height) / 2; // you might like to subtract a little to position it slightly higher than half way
var left = (screen_width - box_width) / 2;
    popup.css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'top':top, 'left':left });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     popup();
  });
})
```

I tried creating a jsfiddle to reproduce the problem but it seems jsfiddle can't do `.get`or `.ajax`since it couldn't load a page from the internet to the DIV.

What can you propose? There should be a clear solution to this and transparancy really should not be a default state for an element so how come the element renders with transparency?

The HTML is trivial

```
<div class="newpopup">
</div>
<button id="mypopup">popup</button>
```

My CSS which is like it is never reached is this

```
.newpopup {
z-index:100;
 position: absolute; 
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:#ffffff; //not working
}
```

And the HTML that is the actual popup / div is this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head><link href="css_js/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>popup</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" class="TB_nb">
  <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök person/företag</h2> 
</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display = 'none';" >X</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<h2 class="pusher">Sök person/företag</h2>
<div id="Vsok">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='none'" class="link_sm">Visa s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

</div>

<div id="sokF">

<div style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span onClick="getElementById('sokF').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='', getElementById('Vsok').style.display=''" class="link_sm">D&ouml;lj s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;" class="fontS80">
<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Fysisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;rnamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchFornamn" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Efternamn:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchEfternamn" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset style="border: 1px solid Grey; display:inline;"><legend class="small">Juridisk</legend> 
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;F&ouml;retag:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchForetag" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">&nbsp;Organisationsnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60" name="searchOrgNummer" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
</fieldset> <br><br>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Attention, c/o etc.:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postadress:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Postnummer:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="30"></div>
<div class="clear"></div> -->

<div class="fl30">Postort:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40" name="searchPostort" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Land:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="2" name="searchLandKod" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">&nbsp;
                    <select name="searchLand" onkeyup="doSubmitByEnter('Namnsokning', 'search')">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">---------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<!-- <div class="fl30">Region:</div>
<div class="fl20"><select name="">
                        <option value="1" SELECTED></option>
                        <option value="2"></option>
                        <option value="3"></option>
                        <option value="4"></option>
                        <option value="5">-----------------------------------------------</option>
</select></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="fl30">Tel:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">Fax:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="40"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="fl30">E-post:</div>
<div class="fl50"><input type="text" size="60"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
 -->
<div class="fl50">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="fl5"><input type="button" value="Rensa"></div>
<div class="fl10"><input type="button" value="  S&ouml;k  " onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Namnsokning', 'search')"></div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

</div>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center">
<tr>    
    <td><h3>Sökresultat:</h3></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="4">En massa text <span class="link">Hj&auml;lp!</span> </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td><input type="button" value="Visa alla"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="smallb">
    <td>Antal &auml;renden: 527</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Visa &auml;renden: &#60;&#60; 1-200 201-400 401-527 &#62;&#62; </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="sortable" id="unique_id">
<tr>
    <th class="thkant">F&ouml;rnamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Efternamn</th>
    <th class="thkant">Adress</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postnr</th>
    <th class="thkant">Postort</th>
    <th class="thkant">Region</th>
    <th class="thkant">Land</th>
    <th class="thkant">Telefonnummer</th>
</tr>


</table>


<div id="bottomV">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" id="visaknapp" value="Visa" disabled style="width:150px;" onClick="getElementById('sokR').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='none', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='', getElementById('sokF').style.display='none'"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" disabled style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="bottomA" style="display: none">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><input type="button" value="&Auml;ndra i register" style="width:150px;"></td>
<td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt" style="width:150px;" class="checkmargin"><input type="button" value="Infoga" style="width:150px;"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I understand your code, the popup contains a full html page with <!DOCTYPE> <html> <head> <body> and everything. If you want to put this into the middle of your page, you have to put it inside a iframe. To put it inside a <div> will probably break your page.

Comment: @aaberg Should I instead just use a table for my popup? Does it have to do with my problem getting the popup normal?

Comment: No, you need to remove the header and tail section from your markup that's being placed into the popup (as the page already has a head section etc), or place it into an `iFrame` - which is then a new window and will need all the header tags

Comment: @RemarkLima Isn't that what I said? I removed the html header and tail section from the popup and what is left is just the table and the divs that are inside the body. But this doesn't answer the question. I could fix it to not be a complete page and I don't think it should be an iframe. Thank you.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz apologies, I misread your statement and thought you were planning on injecting the data into a `table`, not a `div`. So yes, you are right, as long as it's removed from the `data` (as per my answer). And you're saying, once this has been done it is still transparant?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz It might fix your problem. I'm not shure. I just know, that unexpected behavior might happen, when doing things that aren't allowed in terms of the html specifications.

Comment: @aaberg Thanks for the comment. I had to wait and get back and fix a more basic version of the page with just DIVs without JQuery and now that works so now I can try this modularization with JQuery so that popups load from separate files instead of prefetching all the 9 popups' content at the same request. I'm going to look more into this during the next couple of days and if I find something interesting I'll post it here.

Comment: @RemarkLima Thank you for the comment. I've gotten onwards with this problem and I expect it to get solved with some work pretty soon. I have another option to make my popups without JQuery but then they are not draggable / repositionable and I must load the entire DIV contents to all popups at the same request which is how it works now and produces execessive amounts of HTML, about 5000 rows where 2000 rows ould be enough. So when I can modularize this page it will get much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There should be a clear solution to this and transparancy really
>   should not be a default state for an element so how come the element
>   renders with transparency?

Actually, unless you specify an explicit background colour for an element the default *is* that they are transparent.  This is so that the real page background can show through.

Just putting a background colour (and a z-Index if appropriate) on the popup div *should* then make it appear as an overlay as expected.

If it's not working then *something* is preventing the (correct) CSS you've supplied from being used.

Perhaps you should remove the extra HTML body etc from the loaded page?  You shouldn't have two `<body>` tags present in the page at once.  If you can't change the loaded page (e.g. if it's also used as a standalone page) then try something like:

```
popup.empty().append($('body', data).children());
```

instead of:

```
popup.html(data);
```

Comment: @NickRosencrantz no, transparency is _absolutely_ the right default behaviour.  You need to establish why your (correct) CSS isn't being applied, not complain about the defaults.

Comment: OK I was wrong and transperancy is good default. I think I can fix it anyhow if we agree that it is in the CSS that I should look and this is not DIVs that are unclosed or faulty / nested. I could make a basic version of thee page with popups that don't use JQuery and just are DIVs that are rendered with CSS and that is an OK solution while it will be much better with JQuery where elements can be respoitioned and draggable. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz you're welcome - I suggest reading up on "CSS specificity rules" to help understand why sometimes rules get ignored.

Answer (score 2):

use following code to apply the background color to the div

$(".newpopup ").css('background-color', 'white');

Comment: Tried it with no change. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: sorry to inform you that there were a blank space after .newpopup kindly use this one $(".newpopup").css('background-color', 'white'); and try once. inform if wont work

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I tried it now without the whitespace and same result, not working. I suspect my page might have a corrupt DOM structure from e.g. unclosed elements that trashes the page. I've managed to fix the old way that popups were rendered, loaded directly from the same page and not repositionable / not draggable but at least it's something we can use.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm reading this right, your jQuery script is reading a `.jsp` file, which has the full header setion, body etc...

You should either place the contents of the popup into an `iFrame` or strip out all the tags before (and including) the `<body>` and after (and including) `</body>`

Comment: actually he only appears to be _filling_ the element, not creating it.

Comment: That's true on looking again. However, he's still loading the whole head section into it so it's `iFrame` or lose the header. (editing answer with your comments in mind)

Comment: I had to rework the page and now I got it working with popups that don't use JQuery, and I reckon it can be even better if I do it the way we've been talking about here i.e. popups with JQuery that are repositionable and draggable which my normal DIVs aren't. So within the next few days I'm going to go at this use case again having a much better base to work on this time. Many thanks for helping me out :-)

Comment: Good to hear @NickRosencrantz! Have a look at the built in jQuery UI modal dialouge http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ or something like http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Alert+-+Javascript+dialogue+controls to get you started :)

Answer (score 0):

you will try this attributes in .newpopup class

```
'overlayShow'   : true,
'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
'opacity'       : '0.80';
```

or

```
#popup {
margin: 0 auto;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
z-index:501;
background: #effeef;
position: absolute;
padding:0;
top: 0;
-moz-opacity:0.80;
-khtml-opacity: 0.80;

opacity: 0.80;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

#window {
padding:0;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 3px solid #d3d4d3;
background:url(sign_in_bg.gif) repeat-x;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 45%;
}

<div id="popup" align="center" style="display:none">
<div id="window" align="center">
content....
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it and no change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try this within the next couple of days. I reworked the base of the page so that it can get more modular now. Output is 5000 rows of HTML which is a bit painful to troubleshoot, however I think we can get it down to about 2000 rows if I switch the DIVs to use JQuery instead that will load the DIV contents from a file instead of prefetching 9 popups at the same time with the original request.